# translate the technical term from Germany to English in SharePoint-Websites

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I want to correctly translate the technical term from German into English or vice versa in SharePoint websites. The automatic translator of Sharepoint can not translate German technical terms correctly into English. how can i this problem solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can address this by providing alternate languages in SharePoint or SharePoint Online. For example, in a SharePoint Online, go to **Settings** on a site page and choose **Site Settings**. In the Site Administration section, click **Language Settings**, then choose the language you want in the **Alternate Language** section.

However, it does not translate as expected always , Microsoft well aware of this issue and there is no concrete out of the solution for this.

So as an alternate solution, Microsoft suggests to go with the **[multilingual sites](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-the-variations-feature-for-multilingual-sites-da0b5614-8cf5-4905-a44c-90c2b3f8fbb6?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)**.

The key is to automate page and site creation for each location using what Microsoft calls a "**source-target paradigm**." In this approach, there's a single master site where content is created in your default language, then queued up for translation (by you) to the languages you support; users get those translations in their selected language if available.

For details refer to the below article :

[How to make a SharePoint site multilingual](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.infoworld.com/article/3134718/how-to-make-a-sharepoint-site-multilingual.amp.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer,:) i know how i set the language settings in sharepoint-online. but my problem is with the technical term. the technical term that are in website is not translated correctly.

Comment: I have read the Article in this address:How to make a SharePoint site multilingual,
maybe I have to create another website for each language.
but how can I bring the two websites together in cooperation?

Comment: I think this is possible since you are working in SharePoint online... Example create site A in English, download the site template using the PnP Provisioning template... modify the language parameter in the xml for German locale, rest all retain unchanged.. now create site B for German using this PnP template... then any of these two sites, promote as hub site and connect another site to it..Finally create a Megamenu navigation to maintain both the site from single place.

Comment: thank you so much, can you please introduce me to some articles about this topic?

Comment: It is very simple just go through this MSDN document for PnP template :https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine

Comment: For hub create and association go through this article :https://www.google.com/amp/s/global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/hub-sites-in-sharepoint-online-modern-site/amp/

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: Hi - if this has helped you, could you please mark this as answered, so that it will help to the upcoming visitors.